# Select a column and add its amount with other rows

Tags: sql

I have a sql table, I need sumation of spesific column, i mean add amount of a column to the same column in other rows, any suggestion?

Comment: What DBMS?  More importantly, what have you tried?

Comment: I assume that you have tried something, can you show it? It would help clarifying the issue  you had.

Comment: for example we have a table with 2 column name and mony, i want to calculate amount of whole money

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT SUM(YourColumn) as Sum
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: i tried this but no answer: mysql_query("SELECT id as id FROM $table");

Comment: you forgot the essential. To build a sum, use the function SUM: mysql_query("SELECT SUM(id) as id FROM $table");

Comment: still doesn't work, it returns Resource id #6

Comment: then maybe you can provide some more information to your database structure. What's your value of $table?

Comment: I got it, i should use mysql_fetch_array